# Anaconda installation of Tensorflow fails with Debian 8 VirtualBox

Tags: python, debian, tensorflow

I'm trying to install Tensorflow.

I created a fresh Debian 8 VirtualBox for this purpose. Following the instructions [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/) I downloaded and installed Anaconda with Python 3.

I created a conda environment for Tensorflow and activated it.

When trying to pip install Tensorflow it fails:

```
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The error is

> not a supported wheel on this platform

I found a similar thread where a person had this problem with Python 2.7 and VMware, but their solution didn't work for me (and also not for another person who commented that they were using VirtualBox).

I also tried specifying `pip3` and `pip3.5` rather than just `pip`.

Comment: When within `(tensorflow)` have you verified that the python version is `3.x` using `python --version`?

Comment: @CoryShay Yes, it's `Python 3.5.1:: Continuum Analytics, Inc`

Comment: Have you seen this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1990)? It appears someone had a similar issue and renaming the wheel to `py3-none` resolved their issue.

Comment: @CoryShay Now that I had time to get it right, yes that did work! Since the thread you referred to was on GitHub instead of SO I think you should make that into an official answer

Comment: Good to hear, glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a "known" issue from the following [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1990). Which paraphrased you should be able to download `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl` and change the name of the `.whl` to `tensorflow-0.8.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl` and install it correctly. There has been a change to the [github documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#anaconda-installation) for Tensorflow to set the python version to 3.4 instead of 3.5. However, it appears this change hasn't made it to [Tensorflow.org's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-environment-installation)

```
# Python 3.4
$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.4
```