# Tensorflow on python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Is it possible to install Tensorflow on Python 3.5.1+? And how? without any Conda?

I din not find any useful information and

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

does not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cory Shay recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330362/3574081) a similar question with the same root cause. The present workaround is to download the `.whl` file and *rename* it so that Python 3.5 will happily install it. For example:

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
$ mv tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl tensorflow-0.8.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-0.8.0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```